# Picard Lindelöf uniqueness on subinterval?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Picard-Lindelöf Thm. (local Version): Let $X$ be a Banach space, $f: [0,T] \times B(u_0,r) \to X$ continuous and there exist and $L>0$ such that for all $t \in [0,T], v,u \in B(u_0,r)$ there holds
$||f(t,v)-f(t,u)||\leq L ||u-v||$. Then the initial value problem ($u'(t)=f(t,u(t)),\; \; u(t_0)=u_0$) has an unique solution $u:I \to B(u_0,r)$, with $I:=[t_0-a,t_0+a]$ and $a=\min(\frac{r}{M},\frac{1}{2L})$

($M>0$ is a constant such that $||f(t,v)||\leq M$ for all $(t,v) \in [0,T] \times B(u_0,r)$).

My question: If we considering an Interval $t_0 \in J \subset I$, is then $u|_{J}: J \to B(u_0,r)$  the unique solution of the initial value problem on $J$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is positive.

The restricted solution $u|_J$ can be extended to a maximal solution on an interval that contains $I$. And by unicity on the interval $I$ of the solution, the restricted solution is also unique.